# Testing ApplicationHelper methods that rely on the current controller path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an method in ApplicationHelper

```
def javascript_auto_link_tags
  js_path = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/javascripts"
  js = "#{controller.controller_path}.js"
  javascript_include_tag(js) if FileTest.exist?("#{js_path}/#{js}")
end
```

This should find a javascript file based on the current controller file name and path so controllers/admin/blah_controller.rb would generate "/javascripts/admin/blah.js" and include it if it exists.

In RSpec I'm not sure of the best way to test this since I don't know how the controller is being treated application_helper_spec.rb.

My current test is:

```
it "should load controller specific js" do
  FileTest.should_receive(:exist?).and_return(true)
  helper.javascript_auto_link_tags.should include("/javascripts/spec/rails/example/helper_example_group.js")
end
```

I basically pulled the result by checking for nil, but I don't know if relying on how RSpec treats the controller_path (must be "/spec/rails/example/helper_example_group_controller").

> 'ApplicationHelper for javascript auto
>   link tags should load controller
>   specific css' FAILED expected nil, got
>   ""
>   ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:34:

Is there a better way to explicitly set the controller and path name?

Answer (score 2):

```
  controller.stub!(:controller_path).and_return("foo")
```